# AngularJS $resource custom headers

Tags: angularjs, ajax-request

after a couple of understanding-problems, I have run into really hard probs. I can't get my custom headers to work on the $request from AngularJS. My definition looks like this:

```
$scope.re = $resource('/', {
    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
    }, {
    'updateCart': {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'module': 'Shop',
            'mod_id': '1',
            'event': 'updateCart'
        }
    }
});
```

Also here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Preexo/HwPtn/)

Is this [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876784/1011116) still active?
Is there another way to set custom headers?
Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Looks like the have almost fixed the custom header issue with $resource in Angular 1.1.1 pathological-kerning (2012-11-26) that version is considered unstable though... probably got to wait till next stable release to have this in the stable branch

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

($resource: support custom headers per action (fbdab513, #736))

Comment: In case you are not aware, you can use the lower-level $http service instead of $resource.  $http supports custom headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to fallback to $http for custom header. I was also looking to accomplish similar task but there is no way to do it using $resource.

Comment: Headers which you configure with the global `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post` object will not only apply to all `$http` calls, but also to all `$resource` calls. If you can live with it being configured globally for your entire application, this might be a workaround. See [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http) under "Setting HTTP Headers"

Comment: As a matter of fact I did use `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post`. I thought it obvious so I didn't mentioned it.

Comment: @jigar-patel please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old but I answer for other people like me who were looking for an answer:

```js
return $resource('api/people/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
        min: {
            data: '',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/min+json'},
            isArray: true
        },
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
```

Please do not forget the `data` because otherwise does not set the header.

For people like me loving typing, a builder in typescript can be done as follows:

```js
export class ResourceBuilder {

        static $inject = ['$resource'];

        constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
        }

        private updateAction: ng.resource.IActionDescriptor = {
            method: 'PUT',
            isArray: false
        };

        private minAction: any = {
            data: '',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/min+json'},
            isArray: true
        };

        public getResource(url: string, params?: Object): CrudResourceClass<any> {
            let resource = this.$resource(url, params, {
                update: this.updateAction,
                min: this.minAction
            });
            return <CrudResourceClass<any>> resource;
        }
    }
```

The `minAction` is of type `any` because the `ng.resource.IActionDescriptor` misses that property, I do not know if they have forgot, I will open an issue for that.

I hope it helps.