# How to avoid AngularJS to parse string which is not JSON?

Tags: angularjs

I am using `AngularJS` and currently working with static text files to get data.
I used `factory` to return a `$resource` as,

```
app.factory('TimeSeriesData', function ($resource) {

   return $resource('data/timeSeriesData.txt');

});
```

I also tried to `$http` but `AngularJS` was trying to parse it as JSON using this function in angular.js

```
function fromJson(json) {
  return isString(json)
      ? JSON.parse(json)
      : json;
}
```

I just have plain text data in the text file which is not in a JSON format. The parsing is causing an error in the console.
How do I avoid `AngularJS` to stop parsing it as JSON ?

Comment: It's not implemented yet in the frozen builds. This should work correctly assuming correct headers if you try to build Angular yourself or grab it from GitHub.

Comment: Found it! possible duplicate of [How to specify headers parameter for custom Angular $resource action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791667/how-to-specify-headers-parameter-for-custom-angular-resource-action)

Comment: Try send with the header `Accept: text/plain`. If you use 1.0.7, then use `$http instead`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the only way. If I use the $httpProvider to override defaults, then I have other calls to server that indeed return JSON. So do I need to change the defaults every time before I send the request to the server ?

Comment: Please ignore my comment above. Thanks.