# Header set on $resource not returning proper odata response

Tags: json, angularjs, sharepoint

I am trying to return odata as "nometadata" as listed here: [JSON Light for SharePoint](http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/)

I have set my headers in my factory as follows:

```
appServices.factory('appItems', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Todo Task List')/Items", {},
    {
        'query': { method: "GET", isArray: false },
        'update': { method: 'PATCH' },
        'headers': { Accept: 'application/json;odata=nometadata'}
    }
    );
}]);
```

However, it does not return the nometadata option, but rather defaults to:

```
Key     Value
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
```

How can I get it to pass in the nometadata option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage), the headers object should be placed within an action:

```
appServices.factory('appItems', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
 return $resource("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Todo Task List')/Items", {},
    {
     'query': { method: "GET", isArray: false, headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'} },
     'update': { method: 'PATCH', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'} },
    }
  );
}]);
```

As your code stands, `headers` would become a new action for your resource to be called as: `appItems.headers()` which wouldn't produce/do what you would expect.

To be honest, the docs aren't completely clear on what type `headers:` should be or how to set a header globally for all the `$resource` operations, so you could write your own wrapper around `$http` if adding/overriding actions becomes tedious.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801545/2556428) answer shows another example

Comment: Great explanation and exactly what I needed. It is now returning as desired.