# Angular, content type is not being generated correctly when using resource

Tags: angularjs

I have tried the following command, using resource on Angular:

```js
angular.module('appServices', ['ngResource']).factory('Example', 
        function($resource){

            return $resource('http://api.example.com.br/teste', {}, {
                query: {method:'GET', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
        });
});
```

but the http content type is not being generated correctly, in this case "application/json".

I have seen similar questions like [AngularJS resource not setting Content-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785386/angularjs-resource-not-setting-content-type) ,but I have the lastest Angular version (1.0.6/1.1.4).

What is wrong with the code above?

**Conclusion**

- As mentioned bellow, HTTP Get method should not have a body.
- The attribute headers does not work in the version described above. I used the following command unsuccessfully:
  query: {method:'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
- This way has worked for me:
  $http.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

Comment: As @gargc also asked, are you sure you don't want to set an 'Accept' header? What do you want to achieve by setting the Content-Type here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at the [angular source](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/angular.js), line 8742 in the version 1.1.4:

```
  // strip content-type if data is undefined
  if (isUndefined(config.data)) {
    delete reqHeaders['Content-Type'];
  }
```

The `Content-Type` header gets removed if the request does not contain any data (a request body).

I think this is the expected behaviour since **`GET` requests do not have a body**.

A POST method in the other hand, will set the content-type as you expect, as long it has data in the request body. Try the following:

Change the method to `POST`

```
query: {method:'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
```

And call your resource action with some parameter:

```
Example.query(yourData)
```

In this case the content type is correctly set.

**Edit**:

It seems it also works with get, in this case the data is in the second parameter:

```
Example.query(yourParams, yourData)
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/WkFHH/

Comment: Ok, you're right. I tried with post and Example.query("test"), content type is working just fine, but what should I do to change "Get" content type ? I did the same, Example.query("test") and also Example.query(" "), still not working.

Comment: But why do you need to set the content-type for a GET request? there is not a body/payload in the request, the parameters are in the url. Perhaps is the `Accept` header what you want?

Comment: Anyhow, I've realized that passing the data as a second parameter of the function works for GET and prevents the content-type from being removed. (answer edited)

Comment: You can also get this to work by adding an empty data property to your resource config(a little cleaner IMHO):   

`angular.module('appServices', ['ngResource']).factory('Example', 
        function($resource){

            return $resource('http://api.example.com.br/teste', {}, {
                query: {
                 data: '',
                 method:'GET',
                 headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                }
        });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's still not supported - if you have to set the headers you can use the [$http service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Comment: That's weird, it seems they made it work, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/736. I actually did as they did, but it is not working even though.