# $http.get() with JSON data

Tags: http, angularjs

I'm writing a server app and wanted the client to use data in body to pararmeterize my GET method, like this:

```
# http -v GET http://localhost:3000/url text=123 foo=bar
GET /url HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Content-Length: 29
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.4.0

{
    "foo": "bar", 
    "text": "123"
}
```

In AngularJS I tried:

```
var params = {
    "foo": "bar", 
    "text": "123"
}

// no body
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/url',
  data: params })

// ugly url
// also has its limitation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/url',
  params: params })

// params in body, but I wanted GET
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/url',
  data: params })
```

Is this by design or a bug?

I cannot see why from the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http).

Comment: Are you sure the receiving end supports it? [GET requests with bodies are not forbidden, but not expected either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).

Comment: Forget the docs, go research what GET means in http.

Comment: GET method does not support request body

Comment: I concur... The answer to your question is "use POST instead" - but as it's not a true answer, I'm not risking my rep on it.

Comment: In short it is not possible using GET, if you want to sent the json data as request body I suggest you use PUT or POST

Comment: Somehow [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201929/angular-content-type-is-not-being-generated-correctly-when-using-resource/16203589#16203589)

Comment: @bzlm and gargc, thanks for the links.
I wrote the server so it will definitely supports it :-P.
I also edited the post to add this info in,

Comment: I would take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15656884/665507) as the answer: it's not prohibited but you shouldn't use it as the server may ignore it.

Comment: The best explanation I have seen is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37037066/6440354)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would take this as the answer:

For HTTP, it's not prohibited, but you shouldn't use it as the server may (and **SHOULD**) ignore the body of `GET` request.

Reference: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body/15656884#15656884)

For XHR, body of `GET` and `HEAD` will be ignored (hinted by @jacob-koshy).

Reference: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method