# How can I send a request body with Angular's $http.get?

Tags: http, angularjs

Although not common, it is not expressly forbidden in the spec to make an HTTP GET request with a body. How can I do this with Angular.js? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/search',
  data: requestBody
});
```

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$http.get() with JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210347/http-get-with-json-data)

Comment: do you have to use body? can you add query string params instead?

Comment: You cannot. Some Javascript frameworks/libraries may allow it, but it is not a safe operation because your servers are not obliged to acknowledge a request body in a GET request.