# testing controller method fails throwing HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring, mocking

I have the following mocking

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/bk/getBks?sd="+1262296800000L+"&nod=3"))
    .andDo(print());
```

This is my controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bk")
public class BkController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getBks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<BkDTO>> getBks(@Valid @RequestBody GetBksForm form, BindingResult result) throws ... {
        return ...;
    }
```

}

And my validation form

```
public class GetBksForm {

    @Min(1000000000000L)
    private Long sd;

    @Min(1)
    private int nod;

    setters and getters
}
```

The problem is that it keeps throwing the following exception and I can't figure out why.

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = GET
         Request URI = /bk/getBks
          Parameters = {sd=[1262296800000], nod=[3]}
             Headers = {}

             Handler:
                Type = com.ihbs.booking.BkController
              Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.ihbs.bk.BkDTO>> com.ihbs.bk.BkController.getBks(com.ihbs.bk.GetBksForm,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws ...

               Async:
       Async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 400
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

I looks like it finds the handler but it doesn't know how to read the request and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

According to [RequestBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) javadoc:

> Annotation indicating a method parameter should be bound to the **body
>   of the web request**. The body of the request is passed through an
>   HttpMessageConverter to resolve the method argument depending on the
>   content type of the request. Optionally, automatic validation can be
>   applied by annotating the argument with @Valid.

So if you want to use RequestBody, should put your request params into request body part in JSON format for example and change your unit test as follow:

```
mvc.perform(
            get("/bk/getBks").content("{\"sd\": \"1262296800000L\", \"nod\":\"3\"}").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print());
}
```

Transferring domain objects in this way is better than through request parameters.

---

### **Update**

In the case of binding request parameters to domain object simply remove `@RequestParam` and spring will bind request parameters to domain objects.

Comment: You are right in one way but I know that is a best practice to have the empty body of a GET message and the server should usually ignore the body of the GET message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210347/http-get-with-json-data