# AngularJS $http DELETE request Content-Type header

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

When I make a DELETE request with AngularJS `$resource` module, angular adds a `Content-Type: application/xml` header to request headers. In [AngularJS source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L637), there is a section that removes content-type request header when no parameters sent. But, I don't understand why this is happen, this doesn't works.

Here is how I make delete request:

```
$resource('/my/topics/:topicId').remove({ topicId: 1}, successFn, errorFn
```

And here is which headers browser

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/xml
Cookie:session=0a627145415440740d6cc8cd35d19ba3; __ngDebug=true
Host:localhost:9001
Origin:http://localhost:9001
Referer:http://localhost:9001/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36
```

Where that `Content-Type` header come from?

**EDIT**: I'm using AngularJS 1.2.0rc1

Comment: which version of angular you are using

Comment: Oh, sorry. I added version of AngularJS that I'm using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular, content type is not being generated correctly when using resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201929/angular-content-type-is-not-being-generated-correctly-when-using-resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found workaround: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2149#issuecomment-22664501

I hope somebody merge this fix to angularjs master.