# Unable to get posted data by $_GET, $_POST & $_REQUEST in Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs. I was trying to create a simple application using angularjs.
In a simple application i am not able to print posted data via $_POST, $_GET or$_REQUESTin my php script.
While usingfile_get_contents("php://input")` i am able to print data.

Can any one let me know why $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST are not working?

My Index.html Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title>Search form with AngualrJS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="search.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <form class="well form-search">
        <label>Search:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="test" class="" placeholder="Keywords...">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
        <p class="help-block">Try for example: "php" or "angularjs" or "asdfg"</p>      
    </form>
<pre ng-model="result">
{{result}}
</pre>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

search.js code :

```
function SearchCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.url = 'search.php'; // The url of our search

    // The function that will be executed on button click (ng-click="search()")
    $scope.search = function() {

        // Create the http post request
        // the data holds the keywords
        // The request is a JSON request.
        $http.post($scope.url, { "data" : $scope.test}).
        success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.result = data; // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
        })
        .
        error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;         
        });
    };
}
```

Search.php Code :

```
<?php
// The request is a JSON request.
// We must read the input.
// $_POST or $_GET will not work!

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$objData = json_decode($data);

// perform query or whatever you wish, sample:

/*
$query = 'SELECT * FROM
tbl_content
WHERE
title="'. $objData->data .'"';
*/

// Static array for this demo
$values = array('php', 'web', 'angularjs', 'js');

// Check if the keywords are in our array
if(in_array($objData->data, $values)) {
    echo 'I have found what you\'re looking for!';
}
else {
    echo 'Sorry, no match!';
}
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: We're not going to be able to tell you without an example snippet of what you're trying to do, both on the angular side and on the PHP side.

Comment: hi watcher.. I have included code to my question.

Comment: in search.php $_POST,$_GET not working, Why?

Comment: I'm at a loss.. what is the result of `var_dump($_POST);` in your Search.php?

Comment: nothing..it prints blank array.

Comment: if i print data using file_get_contents. Its print a json

Comment: @watcher... Any luck??

Comment: I found [this](http://getluky.net/2009/02/24/php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available/), but its talking mostly about having a syntax error in php.ini.  What is your setting for `post_max_size` ?

Comment: i have all default setting in php.ini.

Comment: see my answer below. did any of that help fix your issue?

Comment: thanks watcher, i'll check it and get back to you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go along with my comment about a possibility of a bad setting in php.ini, [<s>this article</s>](http://www.bradino.com/php/empty-post-array/)(dead link) (linked through [this one](http://getluky.net/2009/02/24/php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available/), from my comment) also offered this quote:

> If the Content-Type is empty or not recognized in the HTTP message then the PHP $_POST array is empty. Not sure if this is a bug or is by design…

The symptoms being the same, (empty `$_POST` but data available through `php://input`), this brings up the number of possible reasons this error is occurring to two:

1. Syntax error in php.ini `post_max_size` setting
2. Bad value or empty Content-Type header being sent from the front-end

If your setting for `post_max_size` is correct, then it could be that angular is removing the `Content-Type` header for the post. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201929/angular-content-type-is-not-being-generated-correctly-when-using-resource) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194442/angular-content-type-is-not-being-sent-with-http), angular will remove the Content-Type header if there is no payload or an empty payload going along with any request, which I believe is your issue.

Try adding this in your `SearchCtrl`:

```
function SearchCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.url = 'search.php'; // The url of our search
    $scope.test = {test:'test'}; // Add me
    // ...
```

I suspect your `$_POST` array will become filled, since there will now be a Content-Type header being sent along with the request, and actual request data being sent. If that works, it means that your `test` input isn't binding correctly to the scope, or you're submitting empty data.  Try adding a guard clause before the HTTP Request:

```
if($scope.test) {
    $http.post($scope.url, { "data" : $scope.test})
    // ...
```