# Is it possible to change the header config of an AngularJS $resource object?

Tags: rest, angularjs

Here's my code:

```js
var userAuth;
var user = $resource('https://myservice.com/user/:id/', {id: '@_id'} ,{
    login: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            id: 'login'
        },
        transformResponse: function(data) {
            data = angular.fromJson(data);
            userAuth = 'Kinvey '+data._kmd.authtoken;
            return data;
        }
    },
    current: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            id: '_me'
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': userAuth
        }
    }
});
```

I want to be able to use the updated contents of the `userAuth` variable in the headers of the `current` endpoint of the resource, **after** it has been modified in the `transformResponse` of the login call. Is this even possible? If so, how?

**EDIT:** I am using Angular version 1.1.3 - this question is about changing the headers in the resource once they have been set, not settings them initially. Thanks

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using? According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791667/how-to-specify-headers-parameter-for-custom-angular-resource-action setting request headers works since version 1.1.3.

Comment: @pbetkier I am using 1.1.3 - I want to know if it is possible to change the headers after creating the $resource. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using the current stable release (1.0.8), although this feature is documented in the $resource page it has not been released.

[AngularJS resource not setting Content-Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785386/angularjs-resource-not-setting-content-type)

**EDIT:**

See my comment below for the explaination of this code.

```
var customerHeaders = {
    'Authorization' : ''
};
var user = $resource('https://myservice.com/user/:id/', {id: '@_id'} ,{
    login: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            id: 'login'
        },
        transformResponse: function(data) {
            data = angular.fromJson(data);
            customHeaders.Authorization = 'Kinvey '+data._kmd.authtoken;
            return data;
        }
    },
    current: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            id: '_me'
        },
        headers: customHeaders
    }
});
```

Comment: You could create the entire headers object with 'Authorization' as a property and assign the reference to that as the header property in current.  You could then modify the object's properties which would give the updated values.